# How to get table content of database in NestJS?

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs

I created a database in MySQL with the name: `refy`. It contains one table called `app`.

[image: screenshot of table with one entry]

Using NestJS, I am trying to find all columns in the table like this:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { App } from 'src/database/refy/app.entity';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
    constructor(private readonly refyService: AppService) {}

    @Get('/refy')
    findAll(): Promise<App[]> {
        return this.refyService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Entity file has:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({name: 'app'})
export class App {
  
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
  
    @Column()
    name: string;
    
    @Column()
    webhookSecretKey: string;
  
    @Column()
    webhookUrl: string;
  
    @Column()
    clientId: string;
  
    @Column()
    clientSecretKey: string;
}
```

Apparently, the database is well connected and reached;
however, when I use Postman to get the data it gives a 500 error:

[image: screenshot of postman result]

With terminal debug error:

> EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "App" was found

I want it to return data like this:

```
{
    "webhookSecretKey": "1",
    "webhookUrl": "2",
    "clientId": "3",
    "clientSecretKey": "4",
    "id": 5,
    "name": "6"
}
```

Comment: When you get that 500, what does the shell that is running your nest server have? There's most likely debug information in there that isn't being shown

Comment: it says
No metadata for "App" was found.
referring to the Table

Comment: Can you show how you configure the `TypeOrmModule`?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for two main reasons :

1. You have the wrong path in your OrmConfig, update it like this :

```
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}']
```

2. You forgot to add the entity App to the TypeOrmModule.forRoot inside the imports array to the main module :

```
imports: [
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  entities: [App]
}),
],
```